# Messed up printing order after pipe

Tags: c, pipe

The `childc.exe` program is this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
int main()
{
    printf("this is apple pie\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and the main program calls `fork()` and then `execl()` to process `childc.exe`. The code is as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{
    int fd[2];
    if(pipe(fd)==-1)
    {
        printf("pipe failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    pid_t pid=fork();
    if(!pid)
    {
        dup2(fd[1],1);
        close(fd[0]);
        execl("childc.exe","childc.exe",NULL);
    }
    dup2(fd[0],0);
    close(fd[1]);
    char line[100];
    scanf("%[^\n]",line);
    printf("the line is:%sand this is the end\n",line);
    return 0;
}
```

and i wish to have this output:

```
the line is: this is apple pie
and this is the end
```

but the actual output is:

```
and this is the end apple pie
```

Please help.

Comment: Why do you need `<windows.h>`? These should be OS independent POSIX programs.

Comment: @Jens, What if the OP is programming for windows only and compiled a minimal case but forgot to remove that inclusion?

Comment: @AnishRam Then wouldn't it be wise to let the OP know this so s/he can fix the code and make it compilable for the rest of the world? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like unix code, except for the `.exe` and the `<windows.h>`. Running this in cygwin?

The problem appears to be that the child process is printing its output with Windows-style CRLF line terminator, and the parent process's `scanf` is reading up to the LF but not including it because you said `%[^\n]`.

This gets you a string containing a `\r` not followed by `\n`, so when you print it, the cursor goes back to the beginning of the line and the following part of the output overwrites the first part.

Even if run on a real unix with no `\r` to complicate things, you wouldn't get the output you wanted because you didn't allow the `\n` to be included in the `scanf`'ed string and you didn't add one after the `%s` that outputs that string.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using `getline` instead of `scanf` to avoid any platform specific issues, such as those mentioned by Wumpus Q. Wumbley regarding Windows CRLF newlines versus Unix/Linux LF newlines:

```
char *line = NULL;
getline(&line, NULL, stdin)
printf("the line is:%sand this is the end\n",line);
```

Comment: It would be helpful, at least for the OP's author, to mention what kind of "*platform specific issues*" you are referring to.

Comment: Good point, updated to reference Wumpus Q. Wumbley's post where he explains in more detail.